# CombineBy Key implementation error: value _1 is not a member of Double

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark. Can someone help me in understanding the below error while using combineByKey .

```
val combineRdd = filterRdd.combineByKey( (value : Double) => (value  ,1)  , (acc : Double , value : Double) => ( (acc._1 + value ) , (acc._2 +1)) , (acc : Double, value : Double) => acc._1 + value._1 , acc._2 + value._2)
```

Filter Rdd is just

```
scala> filterRdd.first
res6: (Int, Double) = (1,299.98)
```

Error is <console>:31: error: value _1 is not a member of Double

Comment: `value` is a `Double`, yet you're accessing it like a tuple. It has no `_1`.

Comment: Does the variable names in 3 closure in combineByKey has any link across the 3 functions ?

Comment: No, there's no "link" between variable names.

Comment: Yes i have used `(acc : Double, value : Double) => acc._1 + value._1 , acc._2 + value._2)`   3rd closure as if am correct in 3rd closure we are accumulating the values across all partitions. I am not sure where else i used it as Tuple , however i know i have some error in `(acc : Double , value : Double) => ( (acc._1 + value ) , (acc._2 +1))` as  ( acc:Double is actally a tuple with value (value , 1) and i have used Double as type. Kindly suggest and correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code

`val combineRdd = filterRdd.combineByKey( (value : Double) => (value  ,1)  , (acc : (Double, Int)  , value : Double) => ( (acc._1 + value ) , (acc._2 +1)) , (acc : (Double , Int), value : (Double,Int ) ) => (acc._1 + value._1 , acc._2 + value._2))
combineRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Double, Int))] = ShuffledRDD[3] at combineByKey at <console>:31`